# Order form for WP (similar to a wishlist)

Tags: forms

Can anyone **recommend a plugin** to accomplish the following in WP?

**1)** I have a form where a visitor can enter his contact information and list the nice to have items with a price.

*For example:*

```
Item Name   |    Item price in $
--------------------------------
iPhone      |    100 
iPad        |    200
```

**2)** I want the form to be able to calculate total price, add shipping and other fees and display the grand total. If possible, I'd like to also display all this in a different currency using a currency converter. For example,

```
Totals                |    Price in $          |    Price in Euro
-----------------------------------------------------------
Total Items           |    300                 |    200
Total with Fees       |    480
Pre-Payment           |    144
Payment               |    336
```

*Total Items = 100+200 from the example above
Total with fees, pre-payment, and payment are calculated based on a custom formula.*

**3)** I *do not need a shopping cart or e-commerce option*. The visitor fills out the wishlist form, sees the calculated totals and if he wants, submits this form.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) - It's worth the money.